# Is this array count on chrome debugger faulty?

Tags: javascript

[image: Screenshot of chrome debugger tool, where my object has key 3707 and the value is an array of 3 items... however, it was showing 3708 items in the array]

Here's a screenshot of chrome debugger tool, where my object has key 3707 and the value is an array of 3 items... however, it was showing 3708 items in the array

Comment: JavaScript arrays start at index 0. The `.length` of the array will be one more than the largest integer-named property.

Comment: Arrays are 0 based index in JS

Comment: Can you show us the code which generated this data?

Comment: It would help a little if you would explain more completely what it is that you don't understand about the situation.

Comment: I just realized that I initialized my variable as an array and used it as an object. However, since the key I assigned is an integer - it assigned my new array at that particular index which is 3707.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert elements at indexes beyond the initial length of an Array, it will expand and insert `undefined` elements in between.

This example might help you understand what is happening:

```js
var myArray = [];

console.log(myArray); // []
console.log('Length: ' + myArray.length); // 0

myArray[2] = 'foo';

console.log(myArray); // [undefined, undefined, 'foo']
console.log('Length: ' + myArray.length); // 3
```

If you want to check that out on your Array, try doing

`console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedParts));`

and you'll see `[null,null...,['foo','bar']]`.

Comment: Actually, it inserts `undefined` elements. But `undefined` doesn't exist in JSON, so it gets shown as `null`.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are 0 based (first object is position 0) in javascript and many other languages. This means the last index will be `length - 1`

Comment: @blex I'm not sure what you mean as Pointy seems to be saying the exact same thing that I am. And the OP last comment on that thread seems to agree since it was assigned at that index.